# Check if any of the values is in a subquery result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery, cte

I have a complicated subquery that returns a list of order IDs. I need to get a list of customers who have these orders. The problem is that there are two ways of assigning a customer to an order (one of two fields). I could just do stuff like this:

```
 select *
 from Customers
 where orderId in (select...) 
 or secondaryOrderId in (select ...)
```

The problem is that the subquery is enormous, both in time it takes to execute, and in the screen space it takes. Is there a way to check if *one* of the fields contains one of the desired results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
where exists (select * .... 
        where Customers.orderId = ... 
        or Customers.secondaryId = ...
     )
```

Eg, if you were planning on:

```
where orderId in (select value from ...)
or secondaryorderid in (select value from ...)
```

Then you make it so that you only call your subquery once, and build your OR clause into it.

```
 where exists (select * from ... 
        where Customers.orderId = value 
        or Customers.secondaryOrderId = value
     )
```

The whole point of this is to ensure that the complicated subquery is only executed one time. That doesn't happen with a CTE, or by replacing two INs with two EXISTSs.

Answer (score 3):

You query should probably be rewritten as an `exists` instead of an `in`

See [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/05/sql-server-convert-in-to-exists-performance-talk/) for more examples.

Your query would then look something along the lines of

```
select *
from Customers C
where exists (select 'x' from ordertable o where c.orderid = o.orderid) 
or exists (select 'x' from ordertable o where c.secondaryOrderId = o.orderid)
```

If both subqueries are the same you could remove one of them and combine them like so

```
select *
from Customers C
where exists (select 'x' from ordertable o where c.orderid = o.orderid or c.secondaryOrderId = o.orderid)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a Common Table Expression aka `with` clause? It's designed for exactly this purpose (among others).

```
with orderIds as (
  select orderId
  from ...
)
select *
from Customers
where orderId in (select orderId from orderIds) 
or secondaryOrderId in (select orderId from orderIds);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.105%29.aspx for Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: Not really much benefit by doing this in terms of time taken. The CTE isn't cached and will be executed both times it is referenced. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041244/cte-performance-on-execution-plan-is-it-displayed-two-times-or-two-times-proce

Comment: OK. Seems each DBMS handles CTE differently.

Comment: A CTE isn't designed for this purpose. It would still be expanded into the main query twice. Try and see...

Comment: And Microsoft's documentation is misleading "[A CTE] can be thought of as a temporary result set" which I interpreted to mean the results are cached or otherwise stored like a temporary table. Now there's another T-SQL solution that hasn't been mentioned yet.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Welcome to the world of Microsoft documentation :-)

Comment: A temporary table is less likely to perform well, as it prevents many optimisation opportunities.

Comment: You could use the CTE in a join.  It will probably not be faster than the accepted answer, but will almost definitely be faster than the OP's query.